# how to send xml to web service with php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl

I use RESTful webservice and it's show some xml.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <users>
-    <user>
        <id>1</id> 
        <name>Mahesh</name> 
        <profession>Teacher</profession> 
      </user>
  </users>
```

I want to add new xml, send to the webservice.

```
$xml = 
    '<users>
        <user>
          <id>3</id>
          <name>hangga</name>
          <profession>IT</profession>
        </user>
     </users>';
```

Here my php code :

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:18080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml')); //setting content type header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, $xml);//Setting raw post data as xml
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print($result);
```

But nothing happens, web service not show new XML. My question how to add new xml and send it to web service using php? should I use cUrl? is there another way? I really need help, the answer will very appreciated. Thanks all

Comment: you should update the data in your service with the new xml you send in curl request , so when you do the RESTful webservice you will get the updated data.

Comment: so I must create some function code in my RESTful to get my php code?

Comment: I mean , post your data , you get it , and you handler it , then display it .

Comment: what you have done in your **UserService/users** ?

Comment: what mean of this HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type
?

Comment: the man who answer the question delete his answer so I don't know what you have changed in your code.But it tells you that you send the wrong type of data to the server.Well,just show what you have done in your **UserService/users** so you will know how to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm stuck, I new in java and RESTful. is there any other way? thanks for replying it very help :)

Comment: well,there must be a trigger or something that handler the data,or you won't get updated data.You RESTful service retrieves the data for displaying,your  **UserService/users** for updating data,and your curl for logics that handler the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://webservice/example/user';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/xml',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))                                                                       
);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$responses = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```